# What Sun equivalent JRE does websphere 7 has

Tags: websphere

We are upgrading our application and if we use Sun JDK on local it works and its failing on DEV box. we have IBM jdk on our DEV box. What is the SUN equivalent JDK that Websphere 7 has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebSphere 7 supports Java6 and JEE5](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rovr_specs.html).

However, it requires [Java versions shipped with WebSphere itself](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005002). (Most are IBM's own Java SDKs, although I think the Solaris version of WebSphere might ship with Oracle's Java.)